# which eclipse sdk use for android honeycomb tablet application?

Tags: android, sdk, eclipse-plugin

i want to make a honeycomb tablate application.

For this which sdk version preferable in android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, are you wondering which version of Eclipse you need or which version of the Android SDK you need.

Android SDK you need atleast r12 (or higher) as you can see on the Android Developer Page:

> Android 3.0, Revision 2 (July 2011)
>
> Dependencies:
>   **Requires SDK Tools r12 or higher.**

But you can download r13 from here: [Android  SDK r13](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

For the Eclipse Version ([Eclipse Download Site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/))
I would go for either:

- Eclipse IDE For Java Developers
- Eclipse IDE For Java EE Developers

---

Answer (score 1):

You may always use latest SDK version for development, as SDK comes with lot of development tools. You can develop application for any API level using latest SDK.

The way I interpret your questions is, what should be the minimum API level that your application should support.

Well as per my understanding Android-SDK supports tablets from the beginning, but since 1.6 onwards multiple screen support was enhanced and made developer friendly.

From the market-share perspective you may use Android 2.2 or above.

Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) which is specific for Tablets provide really cool features from UI perspective.

So in my opinion if your application targets broad category of customers you may support Android 2.2 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

For Honeycomb development use android sdk version 3.0. See this [Link.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-30-platform-preview-and-updated.html)